# TCP sequence numbers in Actual Transmission vs. in Wireshark Capture

Tags: tcp, wireshark

Whenever, we do a wireshark capture and `Follow`--> `TCP Stream`, we see the sequence numbers as fixed values.

[image]

In reality, if this were the case, the intruder can easily predict the transmission patterns.How is it actually, avoided to ensure a secure communication ?

Comment: For secure communication, SSL/TLS is required.

Comment: TCP does _not_ provide secure communication. That must be handled by something else.

Comment: Note that Wireshark shows relative TCP sequence numbers by default. You can disable that behavior in the TCP protocol preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as a TCP sequence prediction attack. There is a RFC defined to defend against it, [RFC6528](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6528)

In a nutshell, some vendors are responding to the threat by introducing random sequence number generation however overall participation is fairly low.